# Additional directories for Apache 2.2 dependency probing

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

By default Apache 2.2 resolves dependencies, i.e. searches additional dlls for loaded modules, using its root directory - bin.

Now I need to copy everything to root, and that litters it a lot. So I want to extend this algorithm adding an additional directory (subdirectory in root). For example, bin/svn for Subversion's dependencies.

How can can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Which operating system are you running on? It should be searching the system path on Windows (the `PATH` environment variable), or the library path on Linux (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable) - this doesn't sound like normal behaviour

Comment: I'm using Windows 2008 SP2 non-R2. Of course it's looking all default paths, but I'm searching a way how to extend such paths

Comment: Then you could just adjust your environment variable - you can do this for the service from the services control panel IIRC - that's much easier than adjusting the way Apache is meant to work. There is also a `LoadFile` directive which will link a file that you could experiment with, but the environment is the proper way to do it

Comment: Thanks, David. I'll try to change %PATH%, I think it could help